# SharePoint 2010 and the GetGroupCollectionFromUser operation in InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am working on an InfoPath 2010 form which will be submitted to a SP2010 instance and filled out via a web browser.  I am trying to present different views of the form based on the SP User group that the current user belongs to.

On form load I want to check a form status field and check to see if the current user belongs to an approval group.  This group is a SP usergroup and from what I can tell the UserGroup.asmx webservice and the GetGroupCollectionFromUser operation is the one I want.  However, within InfoPath 2010 after I add the data connection the only result field seems to be userLoginName.  This does not seem to be what I want, or if it is, I don't know how to get at the group list contained in that value.

How can I get at the list of SharePoint groups returned?

Answer (score 2):

You need modify the xml schema of the web services:

This post shows how to do it:

http://blog.symprogress.com/2011/05/infopath-list-form-hidedisable-fields-based-on-sharepoint-group-membership/